# React Data Grid fails at src/DataGrid.tsx:268 throwing a : TypeError: rows is undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-data-grid

I am using the example code provided on the React Data Grid website at https://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/docs/examples/simple-grid without any changes :

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import ReactDataGrid from "react-data-grid";
import "./styles.css";

const columns = [
 { key: "id", name: "ID", editable: true },
 { key: "title", name: "Title", editable: true },
 { key: "complete", name: "Complete", editable: true }
];

const rows = [
 { id: 0, title: "Task 1", complete: 20 },
 { id: 1, title: "Task 2", complete: 40 },
 { id: 2, title: "Task 3", complete: 60 }
];

class Example extends React.Component {
 state = { rows };

onGridRowsUpdated = ({ fromRow, toRow, updated }) => {
this.setState(state => {
  const rows = state.rows.slice();
  for (let i = fromRow; i <= toRow; i++) {
    rows[i] = { ...rows[i], ...updated };
  }
  return { rows };
 });
 };
render() {
 return (
  <ReactDataGrid
    columns={columns}
    rowGetter={i => this.state.rows[i]}
    rowsCount={3}
    onGridRowsUpdated={this.onGridRowsUpdated}
    enableCellSelect={true}
  />
);
}
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Example />, rootElement);
```

but got a type error back from React Data Grid. What I am doing wrongly ?

Comment: In fact after some debuging I believe that the class interface ReactDataGrid that has been dowloaded with the npm install command is a simplified class that takes only two props: columns and rows (required) and ignore any other. How do I get/install the full ReactDataGrid Class ?????

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same error (`TypeError: rows is undefined`) trying to use react-data-grid for the first time. The problem is that version `7.0.0-canary.14` was published on npmjs.com recently and all the documentation and examples on the react-data-grid website are for version `6`.

According to the changelog (https://github.com/adazzle/react-data-grid/blob/HEAD/CHANGELOG.md) version `7` has a very different interface which doesn't appear to be documented anywhere at the moment. It also appears to be a canary version and is probably not ready for production use. Frankly, being in the process of evaluating this component, the way this breaking change was published makes me reconsider using this for anything serious.

In the meantime, if you want to use the examples or current documentation you can install an earlier version with

```
npm install react-data-grid@^6.0.0
```

or

```
yarn add react-data-grid@^6.0.0
```

---

Update: There are some examples of the version 7 api usage in the .tsx (not .js) files at https://github.com/adazzle/react-data-grid/tree/canary/stories/demos .

Comment: Indeed I moved back to version 6.1.0 and it is working fine. Thank you